# UITableView navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a app, where I got a tabbar, in the 2nd tabitem, I got a `UITableView`, when the user presses the row on that `UITableView` it must navigate to another `UITableView`(2nd), once on the 2nd `UITableView` we can then navigate to detailview.
Can anyone help me out how to sort this out.
Help much appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UITabBarController * t = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    ResourcesViewController * c = [[ResourcesViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController * n = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:c];
    [c release];
    NSArray * tabs = [NSArray arrayWithObject:n];
    [n release];
    [t setViewControllers:tabs];
    [window addSubview:[n view]];

    //---initialize the array---
    listOfResources = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //---add items---
    [listOfResources addObject:@"Speeches"];
    [listOfResources addObject:@"Publications"];
    [listOfResources addObject:@"Images/Photo Library"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This is `ViewDidLoad` method in the `rootviewController` and I created the next level `UITableView` called `detailtableviewcontroller` but can't call it from this method.

Comment: Post any code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want the following view hierarcy (and corresponding controllers) to deal with this:

```
UITabBarController
        UINavigationController
                UITableViewController
                UITableViewController
                DetailViewController
        AnotherViewControllerForTabBarButton
```

Your *UITabBarController* switches between views one indentation level below it, one of these views will be the *UINavigationController* which will provide the navigation between your various table views that you describe (1 and 2), as well as the detail view once you've drilled far enough down.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are similar questions here:

[How to : Navigation Controller in Tab Bar Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490891/how-to-navigation-controller-in-tab-bar-controller)

[Tab Bar Application With Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller)