# iOS: One NavigationController for each tab from TabBar Controller

Tags: ios, controller, navigation, tabbar

I would like to make an app that is controlled by a TabBar,
but when a tab is selected a navigation controller with the navigation item at the top may be used.

This is the identical behavior of the AppStore, when the Search tab is selected, the Navigation Item have one objective, but in the Updates Tab there is another navigation item.
I think one doesn't affect the other one.

Is there any article or tutorial for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a seperate NavigationController in each tab item. This will give you an independant navigation stack for each tab.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753605/1081831) which has links to the documentation and tutorials on how to implement this.